# How to make a method with recursion using an unknown type of a object?

Tags: java, recursion, casting

I am trying to make a method with recursion. The idea is to get Strings of all declared objects and primitive parameters and the objects and primitives types of their objects. Confused yet? :D And no, in my case I can't use toString().  Here is the method:

```
public String objectToString(Object o) {
    StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder("{" + o.getClass().toString());
    ArrayList<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()));

    for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++) {
        if (fields.get(i).getType().isPrimitive() || fields.get(i).getType().equals(String.class)) {
            returnString.append(", ").append(fields.get(i).getName()).append(":").append(fields.get(i));
            fields.remove(fields.get(i));
        }
    }

    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (!field.getType().isPrimitive() && !field.getType().equals(String.class)) {
            returnString.append(field.getClass()).append(":").append(" {").append(objectToString(field)).append("} ");
        }
    }
    returnString.append("}");
    return returnString.toString();
}
```

Problem I am having is this part:

```
for (Field field : fields) {
            if (!field.getType().isPrimitive() && !field.getType().equals(String.class)) {
                returnString.append(field.getClass()).append(":").append(" {").append(objectToString(field)).append("} ");
            }
        }
```

When I send the field object to objectToString(Object o), it gets a Object of type Field naturally. I can't seem to find a way to cast the Field object to a object of type field.getType(). Is there a way to do this? Since I am really interested in this as a puzzle, let's assume this is the only way to get the desired Strings.

Comment: it is possible to change the code a little bit and use string o instead of object 0 then use the forName(String) method https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)
to do the rest of your work?

Comment: Not really, because the first object that is used to start the method Is a specific one - always different with different declared fields. And of course those fields (object ones) will have different fields declared too. So I can't swap it with a String.

Comment: you can call the method using objectToString( o.getClass().getName());

Comment: Just tested it, I still got a Object of type Field.

Comment: did you use in your append append(objectToString(field.getType().getName()) ?

Comment: Yes I did have.

Comment: It's of type Field, but has 4 fields - that are all String variables. Most likely because getName() returns a String.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237337/discussion-between-justsomeone-and-aratata).